# How to add a section to a form if a specific field is equal to something?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to add a section to a form only if a certain field is equal to something, in my case I'm making a form to create a question, if the response type of this question is chosen to be multiple options I want a new section to be able to create those options but only if that response type is selected.

This is my current form

```
<el-dialog
    :title="modalTitle"
    :loading="loading"
    :visible="dialogFormVisible"
    :visible.sync="dialogFormVisible">

    <el-form label-position="top" ref="form" :model="form" :rules="rules">
        <el-row>
            <el-form-item label="Question" prop="question">
                <el-input v-model="form.question"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
        </el-row>

        <el-row>
            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Section" prop="survey_section_id">
                    <el-select v-model="form.survey_section_id" placeholder="Select">
                        <el-option
                            v-for="section in survey_section"
                            :key="section.id"
                            :label="section.title"
                            :value="section.id">
                        </el-option>
                    </el-select>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
            <el-col :span="12">
                <el-form-item label="Response Type" prop="response_type_id">
                    <el-select v-model="form.response_type_id" placeholder="Select">
                        <el-option
                            v-for="type in response_type"
                            :key="type.id"
                            :label="type.type"
                            :value="type.id">
                        </el-option>
                    </el-select>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>
        <el-row>
            <el-col :span="8">
                <el-form-item label="Optional" prop="optional">
                    <el-switch
                        v-model="form.optional"
                    ></el-switch>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
        </el-row>
    </el-form>
    <span slot="footer">
        <el-button
            type="info"
            @click="cancel()">Cancelar
        </el-button>
        <el-button
            type="primary"
            :loading="loading"
            @click="submit('form')">Guardar
        </el-button>
    </span>
</el-dialog>
```

When the `el-select` for the response type is set as multiple options I would like for another section to appear in the form where those options can be created and saved to the question.

I have tried things like this and similar code just to see if it will appear but nothing happens.

```
<el-row>
    <div v-if="this.response_type_id === 2">
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
</el-row>
```

```
<el-row>
    <div v-if="response_type_id === 2">
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
</el-row>
```

Any help would be appreciated, any other code that I have that you would like to see just ask and I will edit the question and add it.

Comment: Don't use `this` in your template code.  It should be like`v-if="response_type_id === 2"`

Comment: @skribe I tried this also without any luck

Comment: Shouldn't you be binding your v-if to your form object?  `v-if="form.response_type_id === 2"`

Comment: @skribe Put that as the answer, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to reference a property of your `form` object directly with `v-if="response_type_id === 2` You should be using it like this instead.

```
<el-row>
    <div v-if="form.response_type_id === 2">
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>
</el-row>
```